# backbone creating a collection from array of models

Tags: arrays, backbone.js, collections, model, marionette

I have an array of models and I need to turn it into a collection of models, but when I pass it on to my view, it's not being used. I have tried a couple of things, but I can't seem to make it work.

For instance I have tried this:

```
var col = new App.Entities.ProductCollection(productArray);
searchData.set({productObjs : col.toJSON()});
```

ProductArray is an array of models.

```
Views.CollectionProductList = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template : "#collection-product-list-template",
    tagName : "div",
    childView : Views.CollectionProductListItem,
    childViewContainer : "#collection-products",
    initialize : function(){
        var products = this.model.get("productObjs");
        this.collection = new App.Entities.ProductCollection(products);
    }
});
```

I know my views are working, because I use them elsewhere.
When I log this.collection, I get something like this:

```
child {length: 20, models: Array[20], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
length: 20
models: Array[20]
__proto__: Surrogate
```

When I log other collections I usually get _events and _listenIds properties. Anyone knows what is wrong here?

Comment: Solved. I didn't render my view.

Comment: cool! you should close the question.